# How to send data from Html button to php command

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web-applications

[I hope this is helpful now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feyzk.jpg)
As you asked me for the database structure, i created one

I appreciate your help! Thanks in Advance!

What I have so far is the following html Code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test Software</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <label>
         Datum:<br/>
        <input name="date" type="date" placeholder="Datum" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        <p> <form action="#"> </p>
      <label>Station:<br>
           <select name="top5" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/> 
        <option>Choice 1 </option> 
        <option>Choice 2 </option> 
        <option>Choice 3 </option>
        <option>Choice 4 </option>
        <option>Choice 5 </option>
       </select>
   
      </label>
     </form>
   </main>
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="button[Button1]" value="Button 1" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
      <input type="submit" name="button[Button2]" value="Button 2" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
      <input type="submit" name="button[Button3]" value="Button 3" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
      <input type="submit" name="button[Button4]" value="Button 4" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
      <input type="submit" name="button[Button5]" value="Button 5" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
 
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

How cand I send the data Tom a php file and then store it in a Database?

```
DB
CREATE TABLE button_counter (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
datum DATE NOT NULL,
savedate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Button BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Button2 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Button3 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Button4 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
Button5 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Comment: you can use ajax to send the data to php script.

Comment: please show the full code with buttons.Then ill give you the answer with relevant names.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I edited the post and added the full code

Comment: @Astra-Joe let m e have a clear idea. Does user can click same button number of times and you need to store its count in db. Am I right?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha, yes the user chooses the date & choicfrom select tag and then clicks the different Buttons, and this has to be stored in db. for example if the user clicks 5 times on button1 and 3 times on button2, this has to be stored for the current date & select tag until a new select tag or date is choosen

Comment: @Astra-Joe to give you a clear answer one more thing to be clear. Just imagine if i click button 1 5 times does it save in db as current date and time with five times or just current time and date with button click count. Also please update you question with a snap of your table you wish to upload data.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha For example if I click button1 5 times, it has to save in db current date and selected choice tag with counted clicks on each button.

Comment: @Astra-Joe ok please attach a snap of you db table

Comment: @NipunTharuksha is that what you mean? I have created a SQL but not sure if this is correct

Comment: @Astra-Joe if you could provide the structer of the db i can provide a clear code

Comment: @NipunTharuksha There should be a Table for each date, choice, and button, where the data is stored in .
Example in my answer

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I attached an example in my Question, was this helpful?

Comment: @Astra-Joe give me  10 min Im testing the code. Ill add an answer within next 10min

Comment: @Astra-Joe check the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changed your code as bellow and check. Its working. In your question I can see that date field to be filled with current time stamp. But there is a input field to select a date for user. So i i modified your code assuming that user will pic the date. Please see the below code and if you get what you need please mark it as an answer. Thanks

**index.php**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test Software</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var counter1 = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '#button01', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counter1++;
            $("#button01").text('You have clicked' + counter1);
            $("#hidde_val_of_button01").val(counter1);
        });
        var counter2 = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '#button02', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counter2++;
            $("#button02").text('You have clicked' + counter2);
            $("#hidde_val_of_button02").val(counter2);
        });
        var counter3 = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '#button03', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counter3++;
            $("#button03").text('You have clicked' + counter3);
            $("#hidde_val_of_button03").val(counter3);
        });
        var counter4 = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '#button04', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counter4++;
            $("#button04").text('You have clicked' + counter4);
            $("#hidde_val_of_button04").val(counter4);
        });
        var counter5 = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '#button05', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counter5++;
            $("#button05").text('You have clicked' + counter5);
            $("#hidde_val_of_button05").val(counter5);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
        <label>
            Datum:
            <br/>
            <input name="date" type="date" placeholder="Datum" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <p> </p>
            <label>Station:
                <br>
                <select name="top5" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;" />
                <option>Choice 1 </option>
                <option>Choice 2 </option>
                <option>Choice 3 </option>
                <option>Choice 4 </option>
                <option>Choice 5 </option>
                </select>

            </label>

            </main>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button id="button01" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Button 1</button>
            <!--Using hiddne text input typeto pass the data!-->
            <input type="text" hidden value="0" id="hidde_val_of_button01" name="button01" />

            <button id="button02" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Button 2</button>
            <!--Using hiddne text input typeto pass the data!-->
            <input type="text" hidden value="0" id="hidde_val_of_button02" name="button02" />

            <button id="button03" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Button 3</button>
            <!--Using hiddne text input typeto pass the data!-->
            <input type="text" hidden value="" id="hidde_val_of_button03" name="button03" />

            <button id="button04" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Button 4</button>
            <!--Using hiddne text input typeto pass the data!-->
            <input type="text" hidden value="" id="hidde_val_of_button04" name="button04" />

            <button id="button05" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;">Button 5</button>
            <!--Using hiddne text input typeto pass the data!-->
            <input type="text" hidden value="" id="hidde_val_of_button05" name="button05" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;background-color:green;">Submit</button>
              <br/>
                 <textarea name="comment" >Enter your comment here...</textarea>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php

//FETCH DATA
$date = $_POST['date'];
$option = $_POST['top5'];
$btn01 = $_POST['button01'];
$btn02 = $_POST['button02'];
$btn03 = $_POST['button03'];
$btn04 = $_POST['button04'];
$btn05 = $_POST['button05'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

// echo $date."<br/>";
// echo $option."<br/>" ;
// echo $btn01."<br/>" ;
// echo $btn02."<br/>" ;
// echo $btn03."<br/>" ;
// echo $btn04."<br/>" ;
// echo  $btn05."<br/>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO your_table_name(Date,Choice,Button_01,Button_02,Button_03,Button_04,Button_05,comment) VALUES ($date,$option,$btn01,$btn02,$btn03,$btn04,$btn05,$comment) ";

?>
```

Comment: Do not use this code as is. It is vulnerable to SQL injection if this SQL is ever executed and might break your application. Use prepared statements if you are going to access the DB.

Comment: @Dharman i have just gave him an idea. He should know how to use SQL

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Is it possible to print out on the page how many Buttons were clicked for each choice? 
For example for Choice 1, Date xx/xx/xxxx, button1 (6x),  button2 (9x) …
I want to show how many times each button was clicked for each choice and date , for statistics

Comment: @Astra-Joe Im not clear what you asking. Do you mean that before submitting you want to show number of times that button was clicked

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I ment that I want to Display on my page the data stored in my database. Now I'm trying to create a database and then I want to Display the stored data on the page. Maybe I should start a new Question for this?
echo "<tr> <td>Date</td> <td>Choice</td>";
   echo "<td>Button1</td> <td>Button2</td>";
   echo "<td>Button3</td> <td>Button4</td>";
   echo "<td>Button5</td> </tr>";

Comment: @Astra-Joe are you asking to fetch data from the database and display?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha yes exactly!
For this Project i have 3 aims that I want to make
1. I want to fetch Data from the database and Display
2. I want to make a counter where I can see how many times which button was clicked for all Dates and stations but with a reset button
3. I want to make the page also work offline with offline aplication Cache
Maybe it is the easiest way to start with point 1.

Comment: @Astra-Joe show me your current database and Ill show you how to fetch and display

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will contact you today!

Comment: @Astra-Joe I have deleted the number hope you grabbed it. However if you provide the current database structure I can provide you the code

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Yes thanks I saved the number!
" if you provide the current database structure" Do you mean that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P696.png ?

Comment: @Astra-Joe 1st develop your DB and related tables. So that show me the table.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Hi, I edited my Question and added the structure of the db, this is what you wanted, right? Btw do you have WhatsApp or similar?

Comment: @Astra-Joe I think you have my number

Answer (score 1):

Please format you html code properly. 
A properly formatted code is here:
Add js function on each button click and in these function increment relevant counter and set in another input field.

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Software</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
    <label>
    Datum:<br/>
    </label>
    <input name="date" type="date" placeholder="Datum" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    <label>Station:<br>
    </label>
    <select name="top5" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    <option>Choice 1 </option>
    <option>Choice 2 </option>
    <option>Choice 3 </option>
    <option>Choice 4 </option>
    <option>Choice 5 </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="button[Button1]" value="Button 1" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button[Button2]" value="Button 2" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button[Button3]" value="Button 3" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button[Button4]" value="Button 4" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button[Button5]" value="Button 5" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;"/>
    </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple form submission you can use attributes of form tag.

Eg: `<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"  enctype= "multipart/form-data">`

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is use for same page redirection with data of form with it's method (`POST` & `GET`).

For check the form data available on page and Insert data in Database, this may help you:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$data=$_POST['name']; 
$insert="INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES('".$data."')";
if ($conn->query($insert) === TRUE) {  echo "Successfully Inserted";
}else{  echo "error insert";  }
}
```

Comment: yeah i know @Dharman but here he's not talking or asking about any security. Atleast read question and try to help others.

Answer (score 0):

@astra-joe This post is to show how to fetch data from DB table and how to display them.

> This is the DB table I created for testing

[image: db table user]
In here what I'm trying to do is 1st create DB credentials and then via those credentials connection will be created.

Then check the connection and if connection fails display the error `($conn->connect_error)`.

Then I create bootstrap table and first define the table header.

Now create a `sql` statement to fetch data from DB table

Then **query the sql** statement with connection `$result`

Now check the number of rows that out put the result `if ($result->num_rows > 0)`

If `$result>0` it means that data being fetched from db successfully.So that each data will be loop within a while loop with bootstrap table

If `$result<0` this means no data being fetched so that output will be

> no data to be fetched.
>
> Check this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
         crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         $servername ="localhost";//these credititlas to be updated according to your DB
         $username ="root";//these credititlas to be updated according to your DB
         $password ="";//these credititlas to be updated according to your DB
         $dbname ="astrajoy";//these credititlas to be updated according to your DB
         // Create connection
         $conn =new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

         // Check connection
         if ($conn->connect_error) {
                 die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
         }
         ?>
      <!-- Bootstrap table header section. This section shouldnt be repeated. So that I have put it before while loop. -->
      <table
         class="table table-bordered table-dark">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th scope="col">Index</th>
               <th scope="col">Date</th>
               <th scope="col">Choice</th>
               <th scope="col">Button_01</th>
               <th scope="col">Button_02</th>
               <th scope="col">Button_03</th>
               <th scope="col">Button_04</th>
               <th scope="col">Button_05</th>
               <th scope="col">Comment</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <?php
               $sql ="SELECT * FROM user";// * mean all in SQL

               //In here query will be excuted with db connetion
               $result = $conn->query($sql);
               // to have a unique ID for a row
               $index =0; 
               //check the result
               if ($result->num_rows>0) {
               // output data of each row
               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               $index++;
               ?>
            <!-- Data display will be started from here -->
            <tr>
               <th scope="row"><?=$index;?></th>
               <td><?=$row['Date'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['Choice'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['Button_01'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['Button_02'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['Button_03'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['Button_04'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['Button_05'];?></td>
               <td><?=$row['comment'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
               }
               } else {
               $conn->close();
               ?>
            <tr>
               <th
                  scope="row"></th>
               <td
                  colspan="7">No data available</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
               }
               ?>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

> Please do update the db table with a field name called **comment**
>
> This is the final result

[image: final result]

Comment: Could you share please the SQL file for Database?